# How to send values from dynamic item of ListView to a particular Intent?

Tags: android

I've a list view:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/activity_history" >
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"></ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

It is populated dinamically and each item use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text" />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear" ></LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/button" android:onClick="editThisItem"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, this layout has an ImageButton with onClick event that calls editThisItem method:

```
public void editThisMeal(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), OpenActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

My issue is how to send to OpenActivity intent the value of "@+id/text"?
I am reinventing the wheel? Exists a way to make ListView editabile?
How to get extras in new Intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably switch to an implementation of either `ListAdapter` or `BaseAdapter` for backing your ListView. Then in the adapter's `getView()` method, where you will inflate your row layout, you can set an `onClickListener` for each button with the correct callback.

Alternatively, if you really prefer to use the XML `onClick` callback, you could do it like this:

```
public void editThisMeal(View view) {
    String text = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), OpenActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("sometag", text);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

To then read intent extras sent into in your 'OpenActivity',

```
public void onCreate(Bundle onSaveInstanceState) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null){
        String text = extras.getString("sometag");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying a custom adapter you will want to use OnItemClickListener for your ListView if you want to handle clicking the Entire Row.

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view , int position,
                long id) {
    // Simple Toast to show the position Selected
    Log.d("SELECT_POSITION", "Position For this List Item = "+ position);
}

});
```

Otherwise when you create a reference to the Button element in your ListView's Adapter do

```
   // inside Your getView() Method of the Adapter
   imageButton = (ImageButton) convertView.getViewById(R.id.imageButton);
   imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     // Override OnClick
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
        // Handle Operations .....
     } 

   });
```

Comment: You can use `OnClickListener` if there is no custom Adapter.

Comment: He doesn't mention clicking on the entire row, just the ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a custom adapter for your ListView and you have an arrayList from where you are displaying data on the listView.

Now lets say your ListView and array list are declared as

```
ListView yourListView;

private ArrayList<String[]> ItemData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

Here you can implement

```
yourListView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        editThisMeal(position, view);

    }
});
```

Here the **position** gives the ListItem position which is selected by the user. Now pass the position and  view to your **editThisMeal** method. So that you can start a new activity with the data to be edited as follows.

```
public void editThisMeal(int position, View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), OpenActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("itemData", itemData.get(position));
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: Why startActivityForResult()?

Comment: I guess you want to edit the selected item p(lease correct me i f I am wrong). Then the selected item is attaching to an intent and the next activity will allow the user to edit the data attached. Now to get the edited data back the onActivityResult can be used. Thats why startActivityForResult().

Comment: No sorry, I just need to open an intent passing an extra.

Comment: ok then just replace the startActivityForResult(intent, 1); with startActivity(intent);